# C# 6 Как определить, атомарна операция или нет?

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

Часто бывает необходимо избавиться от лишней синхронизации потоков. В связи с этим возникает вопрос - какие операции атомарны, а какие нет? Как точно разделить все операции в программе на 2 множества?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ruericlippert/2011/07/26/10-2/ и https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh874894.aspx

Comment: Вы неявно предполагаете, что для потокобезопасности достаточно атомарности ваших операций чтения/записи. В подавляющем большинстве случаев это не так.

Comment: Нет, я лишь хочу убрать лишнее. MVP Microsoft же, наоборот, советуют использовать lock везде, где сомневаетесь. Я здесь хочу избавиться от обременяющих иногда сомнений.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Спецификация C#:

> 5.5 Atomicity of variable references
>   Reads and writes of the following data types are atomic: bool, char, byte, sbyte, short, ushort, uint, int, float, and reference types. In addition, reads and writes of enum types with an underlying type in the previous list are also atomic.
>
> Reads and writes of other types, including long, ulong, double, and decimal, as well as user-defined types, are not guaranteed to be atomic. Aside from the library functions designed for that purpose, there is no guarantee of atomic read-modify-write, such as in the case of increment or decrement.

Т.е. атомарна запись и чтение в bool, char, byte, sbyte, short, ushort, uint, int, float, ссылочные типы + базирующися на этих типах перечисленя.

Все остальное - не атомарно, если в msdn по конкретному методу не сказано иначе.

На практике к атомарным методам стандартных классов CLR относятся только методы класса [Interlocked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked(v=vs.110).aspx) - через него можно добиться атомарности инкремента / декремента / обмена значений.

Comment: [и еще вот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745440/what-operations-are-atomic-in-c) и не забыть про [Interlocked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked(v=vs.110).aspx) :)

Comment: @Grundy там в принципе тот же список (но не в виде цитаты). про Interlocked - это те самые "сказано иначе" - не успел сразу вписать :) сейчас допишу в ответ.

Comment: Не, там еще добавка идет, что если платформа 64х битная, ток на уровне CLI атомарными становятся еще и те типы, которые в 8 байт укладываются

Comment: _if you are running C# code on a 64 bit operating system in a 64 bit version of the CLR then reads and writes of 64 bit doubles and long integers are also guaranteed to be atomic._

Comment: @Grundy да, но это большое такое "если" и язык сам по себе этого не гарантирует. Т.е. это просто особенность системы. Что влезло в слово - то атомарно.

Comment: Ага :-) там про это тоже написано :-) типа это не к языку относится а к самой платформе :-)

Comment: @PashaPash Мне кажется или это пункт 12.5, а не 5.5?