# Атомарные и неатомарные операции (java)

Tags: java, многопоточность, атомарность

Как понять, какие операции являются атомарными, а какие неатомарными?

Вот что я нашла [на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/244881/):

> Операция в общей области памяти называется атомарной, если она
>   завершается в один шаг относительно других потоков, имеющих доступ к
>   этой памяти. Во время выполнения такой операции над переменной, ни
>   один поток не может наблюдать изменение наполовину завершенным.
>   Атомарная загрузка гарантирует, что переменная будет загружена целиком
>   в один момент времени. Неатомарные операции не дают такой гарантии.

Т.е. как я поняла, атомарные операции - это достаточно мелкие, выполняющиеся "за один шаг относительно других потоков". Но что значит этот "шаг"?

Один шаг == одной машинной операции? Или чему-то другому? Как определить точно, какие операции относятся к атомарным, а какие к неатомарным?

P.S.: Я нашла похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/558246/c-6-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82), но там речь идёт о C#...

Comment: @Ksenia я не обладаю достаточной квалификацией для того, чтобы дать ее самостоятельно, но в википедии приводится следующая формулировка (хоть она и туманна): [an operation (or set of operations) is atomic, linearizable, indivisible or uninterruptible if it appears to the rest of the system to occur instantaneously.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability). Попробую не забыть накатать вечером свой ответ.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52674/discussion-on-question-by-ksenia-----java).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

#### Как можно определить атомарность?

Атомарность операции чаще всего принято обозначать через ее признак неделимости: операция может либо примениться полностью, либо не примениться вообще. Хорошим примером будет запись значений в массив:

```
public class Curiousity {
    public volatile int[] array;

    public void nonAtomic() {
        array = new int[1];
        array[0] = 1;
    }

    public void probablyAtomic() {
        array = new int[] { 1 };
    }
}
```

При использовании метода `nonAtomic` существует вероятность того, что какой-то поток обратится к `array[0]` в тот момент, когда `array[0]` не проинициализирован, и получит неожиданное значение. При использовании `probablyAtomic` (при том условии, что массив сначала заполняется, а уже потом присваивается - **я сейчас не могу гарантировать, что в java это именно так, но представим, что это правило действует в рамках примера**) такого быть не должно: array всегда содержит либо null, либо проинициализированный массив, но в array[0] не может содержаться что-то, кроме 1. Эта операция неделима, и она не может примениться наполовину, как это было с `nonAtomic` - только либо полностью, либо никак, и весь остальной код может спокойно ожидать, что в array будет либо null, либо значения, не прибегая к дополнительным проверкам.

Кроме того, под атомарностью операции зачастую подразумевают видимость ее результата всем участникам системы, к которой это относится (в данном случае - потокам); это логично, но, на мой взгляд, не является обязательным признаком атомарности.

#### Почему это важно?

Атомарность зачастую проистекает из бизнес-требований приложений: банковские транзакции должны применяться целиком, билеты на концерты заказываться сразу в том количестве, в котором были указаны, и т.д. Конкретно в том контексте, который разбирается (многопоточность в java), задачи более примитивны, но произрастают из тех же требований: например, если пишется веб-приложение, то разбирающий HTTP-запросы сервер должен иметь очередь входящих запросов с атомарным добавлением, иначе есть риск потери входящих запросов, а, следовательно, и деградация качества сервиса. Атомарные операции предоставляют *гарантии* (неделимости), и к ним нужно прибегать, когда эти гарантии необходимы.

Кроме того, атомарные операции *линеаризуемы* - грубо говоря, их выполнение можно разложить в одну линейную историю, в то время как просто операции могут производить граф историй, что в ряде случаев неприемлимо.

#### Почему примитивные операции не являются атомарными сами по себе? Так же было бы проще для всех.

Современные среды исполнения очень сложны и имеют на борту некислый ворох оптимизаций, которые можно сделать с кодом, но, в большинстве случаев, эти оптимизации нарушают гарантии. Так как большинство кода этих гарантий на самом деле не требует, оказалось проще выделить операции с конкретными гарантиями в отдельный класс, нежели наоборот. Чаще всего в пример приводят изменение порядка выражений - процессор и JVM имеют право выполнять выражения не в том порядке, в котором они были описаны в коде, до тех пор, пока программист не будет форсировать определенный порядок выполнения с помощью операций с конкретными гарантиями. Также можно привести пример (не уверен, правда, что формально корректный) с чтением значения из памяти:

```
thread #1: set x = 2
processor #1: save_cache(x, 2)
processor #1: save_memory(x, 2)
thread #2: set x = 1
processor #2: save_cache(x, 1)
processor #2: save_memory(x, 1)
thread #1: read x
processor #1: read_cache(x) = 2 // в то время как х уже был обновлен значением 1 в thread #2
```

Здесь не используется т.н. single source of truth для того, чтобы управлять значением Х, поэтому возможны такие аномалии. Насколько понимаю, чтение и запись напрямую в память (или в память и в общий кэш процессоров) - это как раз то, что форсирует модификатор volatile (здесь могу быть неправ).

Конечно, оптимизированный код выполняется быстрее, но **необходимые гарантии никогда не должны приноситься в жертву производительности кода**.

#### Это относится только к операциям связанным с установкой переменных и прочей процессорной сфере деятельности?

Нет. Любая операция может быть атомарной или неатомарной, например, классические реляционные базы данных гарантируют, что транзакция - которая может состоять из изменений данных на мегабайты - либо применится полностью, либо не будет применена. Процессорные инструкции здесь не имеют никакого отношения; операция может быть атомарной до тех пор, пока она является атомарной сама по себе или ее результат проявляется в виде другой атомарной операции (например, результат транзакции базы данных проявляется в записи в файл).

Кроме того, насколько понимаю, утверждение "инструкция не успела за один цикл - операция неатомарна" тоже неверно, потому что есть некоторые [специализированные инструкции](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2007/readings/i386/LOCK.htm), и никто не мешает атомарно устанавливать какое-либо значение в памяти на входе в защищенный блок и снимать его по выходу.

#### Любая ли операция может быть атомарной?

Нет. Мне очень сильно не хватает квалификации для корректных формулировок, но, насколько понимаю, любая операция, подразумевающая два и более внешних эффекта (сайд-эффекта), не может быть атомарной по определению. Под сайд-эффектом в первую очередь подразумевается взаимодействие с какой-то внешней системой (будь то файловая система или внешнее API), но даже два выражения установки переменных внутри synchronized-блока нельзя признать атомарной операцией, пока одно из них может выкинуть исключение - а это, с учетом OutOfMemoryError и прочих возможных исходов, может быть вообще невозможно.

#### У меня операция с двумя и более сайд-эффектами. Могу ли я все-таки что-нибудь с этим сделать?

Да, можно создать систему с гарантией применения всех операций, но с условием, что любой сайд-эффект может быть вызван неограниченное число раз. Вы можете создать журналируемую систему, которая атомарно записывает запланированные операции, регулярно сверяется с журналом и выполняет то, что еще не применено. Это можно представить следующим образом:

```
client: journal.push {withdrawMoney {card=41111111, cvc=123}, reserveTicket {concert=123}, sendEmail {address=nobody@localhost}}
client: <журнал подтвердил получение и запись задания>
journal: process withdrawMoney
journal: markCompleted withdrawMoney
journal: process reserveTicket
journal: <умирает, не успев записать выполнение reserveTicket>
journal: <восстанавливается>
journal: process reserveTicket # сайд-эффект вызывается еще раз, но только в случае некорректной работы
journal: markCompleted reserveTicket
journal: process sendEmail
journal: markCompleted sendEmail
```

Это обеспечивает прогресс алгоритма, но снимает все обязательства по временным рамкам (с которыми, формально говоря, и без того не все в порядке). В случае, если операции идемпотентны, подобная система будет *рано или поздно* приходить к требуемому состоянию без каких-либо заметных отличий от ожидаемого (за исключением времени выполнения).

#### Как все-таки определить атомарность операций в java?

Первичный источник правды в этом случае - это Java Memory Model, которая определяет, какие допущения и гарантии применяются к коду в JVM. Java Memory Model, впрочем, довольно сложна для понимания и покрывает значительно большую сферу операций, нежели сфера атомарных операций, поэтому в контексте этого вопроса достаточно знать, что модификатор volatile обеспечивает атомарное чтение и запись, а классы Atomic* позволяют производить compare-and-swap операции, чтобы атомарно менять значения, не боясь, что между чтением и записью придет еще одна чья-то запись, а в комментариях ниже на момент прочтения наверняка добавили еще что-то, что я забыл.

Comment: Здесь говорится что 'volatile' не гарантирует атомарность операции: "JRE действительно неявно обеспечивает синхронизацию при доступе к volatile-переменным, но с одной очень большой оговоркой: чтение volatile-переменной и запись в volatile-переменную синхронизированы, а неатомарные операции ― нет." https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/j-5things15/index.html. Мне не понятно.

Answer (score 19):

> Как понять, какие операции являются атомарными, а какие неатомарными?

Рискуя на себя навлечь обвинения в сексизме, таки не удержусь и приведу пример атомарной операции: **беременность** - операция строго атомарная, всегда есть один и только один отец (всякие генные ухищрения вынесем за скобки).

И наоборот пример неатомарной операции: **воспитание ребенка** - увы операция неатомарная, ребенок есть к сожалению субъект множества различных несинхронизированных операций над неокрепшей душой ребенка: мама, папа, бабушка, дедушка, зомбоящик, детсад, школа, друзья, подруги и т.д. по списку.

Comment: Забавное сравнение))))

Comment: Вы, вероятно, имели в виду **оплодотворение**, с которого беременность начинается. Очень внезапный пример, да.

Comment: В общем то да, я намеренно высказался максимально нейтрально :)

Answer (score 10):

Попробую объяснить. Могу ошибаться.

Есть java, исходники компилируются в байткод. Байткод во время выполнения программы преобразуется в машинный код. Одна *инструкция/команда* в байткоде может преобразоваться в несколько инструкций машинного кода. В этом и заключается проблема атомарности. **Процессор не может за раз выполнить одну команду, написанную на языке высокого уровня**: он выполняет машинный код, содержащий последовательность команд. Следовательно, если разные процессоры выполняют манипуляции над одними и теми же данными, то различные инструкции процессоров могут чередоваться.

Приведу пример:

Есть глобальная переменная:

```
public volatile int value = 0;

first-thread {
    value++
}

second-thread{
    value++ 
}
```

Инкрементирование переменной не является атомарной операцией: оно требует, как минимум, три инструкции:

- прочитать данные
- увеличить на единицу
- записать данные

Соответственно, два потока должны выполнить эту последовательность, но порядок их выполнения между ними не определен. Из-за этого и могут возникнуть ситуации вроде следующей:

1. Первый поток прочел данные
2. Второй поток прочел данные
3. Первый поток увеличил значение на 1
4. Второй поток увеличил значение на 1
5. Второй поток записал значение
6. Первый поток записал значение

В результате имеем результат 1, а не 2 как ожидалось.

Чтобы такого не происходило, используют либо синхронизацию, либо атомарные примитивы из пакета `java.util.concurrent`

Comment: Там проблема совсем не в количестве инструкций, можно обновить переменную на одном ядре, но другое об этом знать не будет.

Comment: @etki почему же ? если квант времени истечет во время выполнения инкрементации, то проблема возникнет независимо от количества ядер. Многоядерность только усугубляет положение дел.

Comment: @faoxis потому что проблема не в количестве инструкций.

Comment: @etki правильно, проблема в том, что не все инструкции выполняются за один такт. И если компьютеру надо, чтобы какая-то операция выполнялась за большее число тактов, то он может остановиться на середине данной опереции и перейти к другой. Например, в регистр попало значение из некой переменной i, после этого шедулер переходит к другой задаче, а значение регистра записывает в менеджер контекста. Когда он вернется к задаче, то вернет регистру его прошлое значение, неависимо от того чем равно i.

Comment: @faoxis проблема в том, что это распределенная система, которая ведет себя, как распределенная система. И на нее распространяются все правила про консистентность и не только.

Comment: @etki не очень Вас понял. То есть, с одним процессором проблемы не будет или Вы про атомарность операций ?