# вывод значения общей переменной двух потоков

Tags: java, многопоточность

Пытаюсь разобраться с многопоточностью в java. Вот простенький код:

```
    public class ThreadTest {
    private int counter;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadTest test = new ThreadTest();
        test.increment();
    }
        public void increment(){
            Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
                        counter++;
                    }
                    //System.out.println(counter);
                }
            });

            Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
                        counter++;
                    }
                    //System.out.println(counter);
                }
            });
            thread1.start();
            thread2.start();
            System.out.println(counter);
        }
}
```

Я ожидаю увидеть после отработки двух потоков значение общей переменной, которое будет случайным, но максимум 20. Тем не менее в консоль постоянно выводится 0. При этом, если раскомментировать System.out.println в обоих потоках, то выводятся действительно случайные значения (например, 10 и 20, 20 и 20, 14 и 14). Почему последний System.out.println всегда выводит 0 и как сделать так, чтобы выводилась общая переменная после отработки двух потоков?

Comment: вы стартанули 2 потока, но не ждете, когда потоки выполнятся. То есть вы выводите `System.out.println(counter);` до того, как потоки даже начнут работу. Почитайте побольше про функцию `thread1.start()` и что конкртено она делает. Ну или попробуйте вместо `thread1.start()` вызвать `thread1.run()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть поток и вы создаёте ещё два. При этом `System.out.println(counter);` в основном потоке выполняется сразу после старта двух других (которые, скорей всего, ещё не успели даже запуститься). Чтобы дождаться выполнения другого потока нужно вызвать метод `join()`.

```
thread1.start();
thread2.start();
thread1.join();
thread2.join();
System.out.println(counter);
```

Но это не главная проблема. Основная проблема тут в [состоянии гонки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8) [(Data Race / Состояние гонки)](https://urvanov.ru/2019/03/27/data-race-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8/). Это не видно на цикле из 20 итераций, но сделаем до 10000 и уже вместо ожидаемых 20000 выводится разное число (13208, 10865, 13532 для 3 запусков у меня на машине). Состояние гонки происходит, потому что `counter++;` не [атомарная операция](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) [(Атомарные и неатомарные операции (java))](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/616278/%D0%90%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-java).

Как это исправить? Обернуть нужный участок в `synchronized` блок

```
public class Jclass {
    private int counter;
    final Object mutex = new Object();
    ...
    ...
    public void increment() throws InterruptedException {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                    synchronized (mutext) {
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(r);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(r);

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

Либо использовать атомарные классы

```
public class Jclass {
    private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
    ...
    ...
    public void increment() throws InterruptedException {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                    counter.getAndIncrement(); // эквивалент counter++
                    //counter.incrementAndGet(); // эквивалент ++counter
                    //counter.set(x); // эквивалент counter = x
                    // и другие методы
                }
            }
        };

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(r);
        Thread thread2 = new Thread(r);

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread1.join();
        thread2.join();
        System.out.println(counter.get());
    }
}
```

Comment: Либо использовать volatile

Comment: @DmitryD volatile не поможет, потому что инкремент не атомарная операция

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon, верно, AtomicInteger нужно использовать вместо инкремента, и им делать увеличение счетчика